# Error 500 on some product's page Magento

Tags: magento

I can't find solvation for this problem. Some products is OK, some return me 500 error (without timeout).
Debug mode gave me nothing interesting (identical errors on OK-pages and noOK-pages).
Logs are empty.

Magento 1.9.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

500 is PHP error so please check `view.phtml` file find out error.

Comment: Why other products are OK?

Comment: may be in this product get some additional data which is system does not recognize.

Answer (score 0):

As advice: enable debug mode of your Magento system.

1)
In index.php uncomment this line:

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

And add into your .htaccess

```
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"
```

Then is a chance that you can see an errors

2) 
In addition you can check your logs in /var/log folder

3) check your server logs. Error 500 usually logged in default server logs

Answer (score -1):

500 is PHP error.

Check in template file, try to debug the php code (should in view.phtml file)

I got the same issue and i fixed it by debug in view.phtml file. The code calls a function in the module that i disabled.